# WPF / Winforms editor control for IronPython with code completion

Tags: wpf, winforms, ironpython

I'm looking for a way to add scripting support with IronPython to an existing .net desktop application and need to be able to have code completion for IronPython there. Code completion should work for keywords, classes, variables, etc. as you type or via Ctrl-Space.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think such a thing exists specifically for IronPython. If you don't need it to be fancy you could something like [Scintilla.NET](https://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) and just run it in normal Python mode and get at least some completion (I think it just suggests things already in the editor buffer).

Providing full IntelliSense is a crazy hard problem, but you could check out the [Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://pytools.codeplex.com/) to see how they do it.

Comment: [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) and their [AvalonEdit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit) component might also be worth a look. I suspect that python tools might rely on visual studio core functions that might be proprietary whereas you could look at the full stack in SD.

Comment: The intellisense in SharpDevelop for IronPython is very limited compared with Python Tools for Visual Studio.

Comment: Python Tools for Visual Studio is actually quite good. Its code depends on Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text pretty heavily, but that namespace isn't that complicated and to the degree IntelliSense support is needed it doesn't look like a hard problem to separate intellisense code out.